# How to link constant with variable by assert?

Tags: prolog

I want to add in the DB a constant and a linked variable:

```
?- assertz(my(x, A))
```

So that in the future I can define A and get the only one entry. Sth like that:

```
?- assertz(my(x, A)), ..., A = 2. 
?- my(A, B).
A = x,
B = 2.
```

Can this be done?

Comment: @GuyCoder I just wanted to be clear. I want to add a pair of a constant and a variable in the DB so I can use this variable further and its value in the DB will change.

Comment: @GuyCoder Looks like I have to find another solution without using DB. The problem is that I'll need 1 more argument and write my own foldl, well, okay. Thanks anyway

Comment: @GuyCoder Well I'm trying to implement the Hindley - Milner algorithm. I've a tree and each time I'm in a leaf and it has no type or we know that it has A type (like a variable), I want to link it with a variable. i.e. I parse "inc (inc 10)", inc has "A" type, so I want to bound "inc" with some variable, save it in DB i.e. myDB(inc, A) and pass it further, so when I'll figure out it's type it's automatically changed.

Comment: But looks like it's not possible and the only solution is to create a list with such bounds, and pass it as a variable during all the parsing.

Comment: `I want to link it with a variable.` I get what you seek and how you are thinking but the way to do this in Prolog and many other languages that use bound variables is that the input is the tree without types and the output is the tree with the inferred types. So what you do when you get to the variable (leaf of the tree) is to add that to the output tree with an enhanced term, e.g. `var(X)` would be from the input tree and the output tree would have `var(X,int)`. This way there is no linking needed. Does that make sense? Hard to explain it all in a comment. :(

Comment: That's a very interesting idea, but I don't get the way you build a new tree

Comment: @GuyCoder It's sad, but thanks for the help anyway. I'll try to come up with something by myself.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in the comments your idea of a link like a pointer is not the way to approach solving your problem.

A common solution is to walk the tree and construct a new tree as you walk the tree by replacing the leaf of the tree with a new leaf that contains the value from the input tree along with the associated value, what you are thinking should be linked.

Since you are somewhat new to Prolog I will do this with two examples. The first will just walk a tree and only return true when successfully walked. It can be used to understand how to walk a tree and run with gtrace to single step the code to understand it.

The second example will expand on the tree walk and add the type (link as you think) to the leaf item. The the old leaf for something simple like an atom `a`, will become a new leaf in the tree like `(a,atom)`.

Also this was quickly written as a demonstration only. I am sure it will have problems if pressed into doing anything more than the single example.

```
:- module(example,
    [
      example/1
    ]).

example(walk) :-
  Term = term_size(a(1,"Hello",'Atom',1+2,[a,$,T])),
  walk(Term).

example(infer_type) :-
  Term = term_size(a(1,"Hello",'Atom',1+2,[a,$,T])),
  infer_type(Term,Is),
  write(Is).

walk([])  :-                   !.
walk([T]) :- var(T),           !.
walk(L)   :- is_list(L),       !, L = [H|T], walk(H), walk(T).
walk(T)   :- compound(T),      !, T =.. [_|Args], !, walk(Args).
walk(T)   :- integer(T),       !.
walk(T)   :- var(T),           !.
walk(T)   :- atomic(T),        !.
walk(T)   :- T =.. [Arg|Args], !, walk(Arg), walk(Args).


infer_type([],[])         :-                   !.
infer_type([T],[(T,var)]) :- var(T),           !.
infer_type(L,S)           :- is_list(L),       !, L = [H|T], infer_type(H,I), infer_type(T,Is), S = [I|Is].
infer_type(T,S)           :- compound(T),      !, T =.. [F|Args], !, infer_type(Args,Is), S =.. [F|Is].
infer_type(T,(T,integer)) :- integer(T),       !.
infer_type(T,(T,var))     :- var(T),           !.
infer_type(T,(T,atom))    :- atomic(T),        !.
infer_type(T,S)           :- T =.. [Arg|Args], !, infer_type(Arg,I), infer_type(Args,Is), S =.. [I|Is].
```

Example run

Note: I know there are warnings; it is a demo not production code.

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.5.3)


?- working_directory(_,'C:/Users/Groot').
true.

?- [example].
Warning: c:/users/Groot/example.pl:20:
Warning:    Singleton variables: [T]
Warning: c:/users/Groot/example.pl:24:
Warning:    Singleton variables: [T]
true.

?- example(walk).
true.

?- example(infer_type).
term_size(a((1,integer),(Hello,atom),(Atom,atom),(1,integer)+(2,integer),[(a,atom),(($),atom),(_25642,var)]))
true.
```

As an exercise I did not identify the string as a string, the change should be easy.